MySQL ERROR Error Code: 1005. Can't create table (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
Tengo la tabla pedidos que hace referencia a la tabla clientes, pero MySQL me dice que la llave foranea no esta bien formada al momento de crear la tabla pedidos.
Ya revise el nombre de los campos y los tipos de datos de la llave foranea, tanto en la tabla padre como en la tabla hija, pero no encuentro el error. Aqui esta el SQL:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clientes;
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    num_clie INT NOT NULL,
    empresa VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
    rep_clie INT NOT NULL,
    limite_credito DECIMAL(7,2),
    UNIQUE UK_clientes_numclie (num_clie),
    CONSTRAINT PK_clientes_numclie PRIMARY KEY (num_clie),
    CONSTRAINT FK_clientes_repventas_numempl_repclie FOREIGN KEY (rep_clie) REFERENCES repventas(num_empl)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pedidos;
CREATE TABLE pedidos (
    num_pedido INT NOT NULL,
    fecha_pedido DATE NOT NULL,
    clie INT NOT NULL,
    rep INT NOT NULL,
    fab VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    producto VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT,
    importe DECIMAL(8,2),
    UNIQUE UK_num_pedido (num_pedido),
    CONSTRAINT PK_pedidos_num_pedido PRIMARY KEY (num_pedido),
    CONSTRAINT FK_pedidos_clientes_clie_numclie FOREIGN KEY (clie) REFERENCES clientes(num_clie),
    CONSTRAINT FK_pedidos_repventas_rep_numempl FOREIGN KEY (rep) REFERENCES repventas(num_empl),
    CONSTRAINT FK_pedidos_productos_fabproducto_idfabidproducto FOREIGN KEY (fab, producto)     REFERENCES productos(id_fab, id_producto)
);

Gracias por su ayuda :)

How about repventas and productos table? Make sure that all foreign key columns have the same data type as the primary key columns they reference.
